# VBA Excel + using match function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some kind of problem in a piece of code.
I need to find values in a excel book and then copy it to another. The thing is that i need to copy it concept by concept in the right place. The problem is that the file doesnt come every week in the same order.
So i need to  find the concept and then copy the next cell that is the value of that concept.
First of all i use need to locate the correct line so i can start copying (this part is easy and its done).
Secondly, having the correct line, i need to find the concept, which in this example im going to use the "619".
After having find the location of this value i store the value in "c_audiovisual".

```
 On Error GoTo ErrhandlerCAV
         lRowC_AV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(619, Range("A" & line & ":FI" & line), 0) + 1

       'On Error GoTo ErrhandlerCAV
Continue:
        If errorCAV = 1 Then
                c_audiovisual = 0
                errorCAV = 0
        Else
                c_audiovisual = ActiveSheet.Cells(line+ m2, lRowC_AV).Value
        End If
```

I've made a escape in case that this concept isn't present in that line (which sometimes occurs).

Sometimes this piece of code works, and other it doesn't. 
When i'm on debug mode (pressing F8) it works. And when i use small files to look for the values it works. On bigger files sometimes don't.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would say fire up a large file and put a break point in your error trap, then review the data that it is having issue with.  Most likely there is some data scenario you did not allow for.

Comment: What is the value of m2 (which you add to the line value)? Is it a variable defined somewhere, or is it supposed to read `line + 2`? You may need to provide us with a little more context here.

Comment: @KarlRookey yeah, it's a variable. And the error lies on that. This wasn't a code made initially by myself so i'm just picking another guy job. With your comment i was able to see that it was missing the variable "m2" in the place where he was using the match function. So he was applying the match function for a diferent line than the line he wanted causing that this piece of code only worked when m2=0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues. I fixed it with using ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range(...) inside the Match function. Or try ActiveWorkbook as applicable. Let me know if this worked. Curious to know.

Btw I noticed column and row number both are "line". Is that a mistake?